# cmake target link openssl error

Tags: c++, cmake, openssl

Here is my part of  `CMakeLists.txt`.

```
find_package(OpenSSL REQUIRED)

add_executable(
        aes_test
        src/aes_test.cpp
)

MESSAGE(${OPENSSL_FOUND})
MESSAGE(${OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY})

target_link_libraries(
        aes_test
        ${OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY}
)
```

The `MESSAGE`'s output

```
TRUE
/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib/libssl.dylib
```

`cmake` has found `OpenSSL` however when I link my program aes_test with `OpenSSL` there is an link error.

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_AES_decrypt", referenced from:
      _main in aes_test.cpp.o
  "_AES_encrypt", referenced from:
      _main in aes_test.cpp.o
  "_AES_set_decrypt_key", referenced from:
      _main in aes_test.cpp.o
  "_AES_set_encrypt_key", referenced from:
      _main in aes_test.cpp.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
```

In `aes_test.cpp`, I use function `AES_set_encrypt_key` which is defined in `aes.h`. What's wrong ? Can anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Check if the library file that you are trying to link is built for x86_64 architecture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
target_link_libraries(
        aes_test
        ssl
        crypto
)
```

Above code works for me.

Comment: Adding ${OPENSSL_CRYPTO_LIBRARY} to the existing ${OPENSSL_SSL_LIBRARY} would probably be better (and in modern CMake, using OpenSSL::SSL and OpenSSL::Crypto would be better still). But the basic premise that you are missing linking with the 'crypto' library is correct.